# Exellent Export excel sheet border

Tags: javascript, excel, excellentexport

I'm using a js plug in called excellent export to export a table to excel. I want to add cell borders and my table have css borders. But I don't get any borders for excel sheet. Can you please help me with this.

[Owner's blog](http://jordiburgos.com/post/2017/excellentexport-javascript-export-to-excel-csv.html)

```
<a href="#" download="table.xls" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'clone', 'table');">Link</a>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/syek1w20/2/)

thank you

Comment: try using thicker borders, 3, 4, 5px (fiddle does not work for me).

Comment: this generally solves problem in other libraries, but not in your case. check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I know its too late to answer; but may this helps to someone.
I solved this problem by just adding "border" attribute for "table" tag on document ready, as..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     ...
     $('table').attr('border', '1');
}
```

and then,

```
 <a href="#" download="table.xls" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'clone', 'table');">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
     var tableToExcel = (function () {
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function (table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()
```

Copy and paste this code in one js file and button click call this js

Answer (score 1):

Use inline styles for cells, this plugin will clone the table, not css.